# How to grant database user read/write access roles the "new way"?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

OK, so I have a database, a login and a database user assigned to a login. To grant that user db_datareader and db_datawriter access to the database I would do this:

```
USE [mydatabase];
EXEC sp_addrolemember db_datareader, [myuser];
EXEC sp_addrolemember db_datawriter, [myuser];
```

But if I'm reading the [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187750.aspx) correctly, the use of `sp_addrolemember` is discouraged:

> This feature will be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL
>   Server. Avoid using this feature in new development work, and plan to
>   modify applications that currently use this feature. Use ALTER ROLE
>   instead.

So how do you do this with ALTER ROLE? When I do this:

```
ALTER ROLE sys.database_role_members.db_datareader ADD MEMBER [myuser];
```

I get this error:

> Incorrect syntax near ADD MEMBER

Comment: You're using the wrong version of the documentation if you're on 2008. Use the 'Other Versions' drop down to select the one relevant to your version of SQL Server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using sql server 2008 only `sp_addrolemember` will work.

The alter role syntax is only valid for the 2012 version. It is due to that you get an incorrect syntax error